# Firefox extension icon notification indicator

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a firefox extension. I am unsure what api to use to generate icon notifications for extensions, such as the ones in the picture below (the "1" and "3" bubbles).

[image]

I'd imagine it is one of the APIs listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API, however I can't find the right one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using browserAction.setBadgeText().

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText